# Is it possible to link to an existing product image using the Magento Soap API V2?

Tags: image, api, magento, soap

I am using Magento to offer class registrations. I am using the SOAP API V2 to 'clone' classes to a new date.

I would like to re-use the existing class image, as it seems silly to re-upload the same image hundreds of times.

Is it possible to link to an existing image via the API V2?

*catalogProductAttributeMediaCreate*() doesn't appear to want to do it with how I've tried.
*catalogProductAttributeMediaUpdate*() doesn't work either, as an image hasn't been created for that product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this.

```
$proxy = new SoapClient('http://magentohost/api/v2_soap/?wsdl'); // TODO : change url
$sessionId = $proxy->login('apiUser', 'apiKey'); // TODO : change login and pwd if necessary

$result = $proxy->catalogProductAttributeMediaInfo($sessionId, '2', '/b/l/blackberry8100_2.jpg');
var_dump($result);
```

the response :

```
array
  'file' => string '/b/l/blackberry8100_2.jpg' (length=25)
  'label' => string '' (length=0)
  'position' => string '1' (length=1)
  'exclude' => string '0' (length=1)
  'url' => string 'http://magentohost/media/catalog/product/b/l/blackberry8100_2.jpg' (length=71)
  'types' =>
    array
      0 => string 'image' (length=5)
      1 => string 'small_image' (length=11)
      2 => string 'thumbnail' (length=9)
```